Adding Accounts as Campaign Members through Data Loader
So I've enabled Accounts as Campaign Members and as a System Admin I can choose the AccountId through the Data Loader as a field to map but a non-admin User cannot. They can add them in the UI just fine, and they can see AccountID in Workbench, so I have reason to believe that the permissions are there, and that Data Loader allows it but I just cannot find the combination of perms to reveal it. I even added View All and Modify All Accounts since I know Upserts expect that.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385639&type=1 is a good start

Did you try the steps mentioned for contact or lead in the article, for an account? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386155&type=1
